# ExecuteNonQueryAsync sql command gives SP with multiple parameter sets in DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am reading Json and inserting it into a table. I wanted to speed up the program by not having it wait since each insert will be unique.

so for testing reasons I created a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", i);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "test");

    insert.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

I run this and the DB spits back this when I do a trace.

```
exec SP_Insert @id = 1, @type = 'test',@id = 2, @type = 'test',@id = 3, @type = 'test'
```

this then fails to insert since the SP thinks I gave it to many parameters.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `await` and be sure not to add new parameters to each loop.

When re-using parameters like below, you have to set correct [Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter_Size) for the parameter.

```
insert.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
// Note: Set length of the target column. NVarChar -1 maps to nVarchar(max) 
insert.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    insert.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
    insert.Parameters["@type"].Value = "test";

    await insert.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```

Comment: No need to clear the parameters. They can be reused. Add them before the loop and set the `Value` property inside the loop.

Comment: @madreflection Good point, I'll check that and amend answer if this works..

Comment: thank you both, that solved my issue and fixed the same issue that was going to happen on a non asyc function.

Comment: @mobwar - I would also suggest saving the parameter objects, e.g. `var idParameter = insert.Parameters.Add("@id", ...);` and then assigning the value without indexing the collection, e.g. `idParameter.Value = i;`

Answer (score 0):

If you can insert data directly into a table or if you can create a staging table much faster will be using DataTable and bulkCopy instead.

This way you will first load data in the client memory and then send all rows in one bulk operation to SQL Server.

Nice tutorial how to do it is there:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/single-bulk-copy-operations

Use method: `WriteToServer(DataTable)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver